# I am trying to clean install flutter and even though, This error doesn't go. How can I resolve it?

Tags: macos, flutter, sdk

I wanted to reinstall flutter but I am getting this error, how can I resolve it?[image: This is the error that I get]

Comment: Do you have xcode installed?

Comment: no. I do not. but could that be the reason why flutter version shows 0..00 or unknown?

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command to see if there are any dependencies you need to install to complete the setup (for verbose output, add the -v flag):

```
flutter doctor
```

You can update your PATH variable for the current session at the command line, as shown in Get the Flutter SDK. You’ll probably want to update this variable permanently, so you can run flutter commands in any terminal session.

The steps for modifying this variable permanently for all terminal sessions are machine-specific. Typically you add a line to a file that is executed whenever you open a new window. For example:

Determine the directory where you placed the Flutter SDK. You need this in Step 3.
Open (or create) the rc file for your shell. Typing echo $SHELL in your Terminal tells you which shell you’re using. If you’re using Bash, edit $HOME/.bash_profile or $HOME/.bashrc. If you’re using Z shell, edit $HOME/.zshrc. If you’re using a different shell, the file path and filename will be different on your machine.

```
 export PATH="$PATH:[PATH_TO_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY]/flutter/bin"
```